# Is there an extension to quickly clear / flush / invalidate the Firefox DNS cache (Quantum)

Tags: firefox, dns, firefox-extensions, cache, firefox-quantum

There used to be several DNS flushing add-ons prior to Firefox Quantum. Are any currently available? Is this no longer something that's accessible through the addon API?

Yes, I realize that I can do this through:

```
Options/Preferences
→ Privacy & Security
→ Scroll down to History
→ Click "Clear History"
→ Set Time Range to "Today"
→ Deselect everything except "Cache"
→ Click "Clear Now"
```

but this is slow and cumbersome and would be better done through a clickable button.

Thank you for any suggestions!